# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'ClientCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-controller

I am still a new programmer with Angularjs and I am having an issue adding a controller to my site. I have two other controllers connected to the site and working fine but this one for some reason isn't being recognized.

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['JobCtrl','JobSvc','WebsiteCtrl', 'WebsiteSvc','ClientCtrl','ClientSvc','ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);
```

my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ClientCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal('Add')">Add Client</button>
            </div>
            <input ng-model="searchKeyword" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6 pull-right" placeholder="Search Clients...">
            <h2 class="col-md-4">Clients</h2>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
            <td class="text-center">
                <strong>Name</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <strong>Actions</strong>
            </td>
            </thead>

            <tbody ng-repeat="c in model.clientList | filter: searchKeyword ">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        {{c.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" ng-click="selectClient(c); showModal('Edit', c)" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" ng-click="selectClient(c); showModal('Delete', c)" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller

```
    angular.module('app')
.controller('ClientCtrl', ['ClientService', '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function (ClientService, $scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {
    //$scope.model = ClientService.getClients();
    $scope.new = {
        Client: {}
    };

    //create alerts when page reloads after crud functions
    if (localStorage.getItem("Success")) {
        $scope.alert = "Success";
        $scope.alertMessage = localStorage.getItem("Success");
        localStorage.clear();
    } else if (localStorage.getItem("Error") && localStorage.getItem("Error") != null) {
        //sometimes get errors even when adding, deleting, updating is successful
        $scope.alert = "Error";
        $scope.alertMessage = localStorage.getItem("Error");
        localStorage.clear();
    };

    getClients();
    function getClients() {
        ClientService.getClients()
        .then(
            function (data) {
                $scope.model = data;
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                console.log("Error while getting clients");
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.addClient = function () {
        ClientService.addClient()
        .then(
            function (success) {
                localStorage.setItem("Success", "Added client Id:" + success.Id + " Successfully!");
            },
            function (error) {
                localStorage.setItem("Error", "Error while adding client! " + error.status + ":" + error.statusText);
                alert(error.status + " " + error.statusText);
            }
        );
        //location.reload();
    }

    $scope.updateClient = function () {
        ClientService.updateClient()
        .then(
        function (success) {
            localStorage.setItem("Success", "Updated client Id:" + success.Id + " Successfully!");
        },
        function (error) {
            localStorage.setItem("Error", "Error while updating client! " + error.status + ":" + error.statusText);
            alert(error.status + " " + error.statusText);
        }
        );
        //location.reload();
    }

    $scope.deleteClient() = function () {
        ClientService.deleteClient()
        .then(
            function (success) {
                localStorage.setItem("Success", "Deleted client Id: " + success.Id + " Successfully!");
            },
            function (error) {
                localStorage.setItem("Error", "Error while deleting client: " + error.status + error.statusText);
                alert(error.status + " " + error.statusText);
            }
        );
        //location reload();
    }

    //select client
    $scope.selectClient = function (client) {
        $scope.selectedClient = client;
    }

    //show modal function
    $scope.showModal = function (action, obj) {
        $scope.showBool = true; //boolean to be able to exit modal after update
        $scope.model.runButtonText = "Run Job"; //this is for run job only
        $scope.$modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            scope: $scope,
            inputs: {
                title: action + " Client"
            },
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: 'app/modal/ClientModals/modal' + action + 'Template.html',
            controller: "JobCtrl",
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false

        });
    }

    //exit modal function
    $scope.exitModal = function () {
        $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

}]);
```

Any help would be fantastic, I just don't understand how my other controllers are considered defined but this one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot one of your dependency (`$uibModalInstance`) in your controller creation:

```
.controller('ClientCtrl', ['ClientService', '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal',
                  function (ClientService, $scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {
```

Should be:

```
.controller('ClientCtrl', ['ClientService', '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance'
                  function (ClientService, $scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't fix it. This would matter due to minification. But regardless if I add the uibModalInstance as a part of the explicit dependency it still gives me the ClientCtrl not defined/ not a function error from angular. Thanks though!

Comment: Did you correctly import the JS file of your controller in your index.html?

Comment: I did not have to do that because I am doing an MVC C# web app and my angular is bundled in with the BundleConfig.cs and rendered on the _Layout.cshtml page. I did not have to reference my controllers anywhere new with my other controllers as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's so weird, I recreated a Controller naming it TestCtrl.js, put it in my app.js dependencies, and called it within my html as ng-controller="TestCtrl" and it works. But I rename it to ClientCtrl and make all the necessary changes to reflect this controller and it fails and says ClientCtrl is undefined. So confused.